# How to download html from webpage with java

Tags: java

I was trying to download a pages html with a quick java program I wrote but I kept getting an error

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript or JavaScript is not 
   turned on. Please enable JavaScript in your browser.<br></noscript>
```

This is the code im using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888"); 

        URL x=new URL("");
        HttpURLConnection hc=(HttpURLConnection)x.openConnection();

        hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0)AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");


        InputStream is=hc.getInputStream();

        int u=0;
        byte[] kj=new byte[1024];
        while((u=is.read(kj))!=-1)
       {
            System.out.write(kj,0,u);
        }
       is.close();
      }
```

Does anyone have any solutions that will actually give me the source html? Thanks!
NOTE: I left the URL blank because it was something private

Comment: Is the error the only thing printed?

Comment: @kittycat3141 heres the full things

Comment: @kittycat3141 [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1owN7gkSijGndLTwikML14qHFKcH6d2fqs091vmIGngY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: no, when i physically go to the webpage and inspect element its the actual html of the page. thats what I want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jsoup. http://jsoup.org/

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
String htmlString = doc.html();
```

Comment: It still gives me the same thing :( I already tried downloading the library and using it earlier in the day. Ive been trying to accomplish this seemingly simple task for over like 3 hours now.

Comment: What is the site you are trying to get the html source of?

Answer (score 0):

That's completely normal. It is put in the HTML code so that if your browser does not support/has Javascript turned off, it will display it. Otherwise, it will ignore it. This is how sites display warnings that Javascript is off.

Comment: but the problem is that it doesnt achieve what I want. Its supposed to store the whole pages html into a string and then print it. Instead I get that junk.

Comment: Which one is it giving you, the one linked above?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the same html that is present if you were to go to inspect element while you are in the web browser.

Comment: @Ukrainian_Reaper I'm confused about which code you want and which code you're getting.